# You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB

Tags: php, mysqli, mariadb

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 's Stone','1','J. K. Rowling','J. K. Rowling','J. K. Rowling','J.
>   K. Rowling','J.' at line 2

CODE:

```
mysqli_query($con,"insert into book(book_title,category_id,author,author_2,author_3,author_4,author_5,book_copies,book_pub,publisher_name,isbn,copyright_year,status,book_barcode,book_image,date_added,remarks)
                VALUES('$book_title','$category_id','$author','$author_2','$author_3','$author_4','$author_5','$book_copies','$book_pub','$publisher_name','$isbn','$copyright_year','$status','$gen','$book_image',NOW(),'$remark')")or die(mysqli_error($con));
```

Comment: Never concatenate SQL strings. Use parameters and this problem as well as lots of security issues will disappear.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: You need to sue the pants off whoever taught you how to database in PHP.

Comment: Looks like your inserting `philosopher's stone` and the quote in it is interfering with the quotes in the SQL.  Which is why using prepared statements will solve the problem and a few others.

Answer (score 1):

Your parameters expand to values that have single quotes that break the syntax. [Use prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) to prevent this ([and other bad things](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)) from happening.

Here's an example of how it could be done ([copied mostly from these examples](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php#refsect1-mysqli.prepare-examples)):

```
if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($con, "insert into book(book_title,category_id,author,author_2,author_3,author_4,author_5,book_copies,book_pub,publisher_name,isbn,copyright_year,status,book_barcode,book_image,date_added,remarks) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,NOW(),?)")) {
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "sdsssssddssdsssss", $book_title,$category_id,$author,$author_2,$author_3,$author_4,$author_5,$book_copies,$book_pub,$publisher_name,$isbn,$copyright_year,$status,$gen,$book_image,$remark);
    mysqli_execute($stmt);
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
}
```